# ruby 2.0 changes for binding and eval

Tags: ruby, eval, ruby-2.0

While migrating code from ruby 1.8.6 to 2.0 I noticed that the behaviour of eval with bindings has changed. I did not find any information about that and the documentation of those methods has not changed its wording.

```
object = Math
binding = object.__send__(:binding)
puts eval("self", binding)
puts eval("sin(0.2)", binding)
```

gives in irb1.8:

```
> Math
> 0.1986…
```

and in irb2.0:

```
> main
> NoMethodError
```

I get the same when using the new `binding.eval("self")`

What is the underlying change, and how can I implement the previous behavior in Ruby 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the following, both from Ruby 2.0:

```
 b = Math.__send__(:binding)
 b.eval("self")
 => main

 b = Math.instance_eval { binding }
 b.eval("self")
 => Math

 # or equivalently...
 b = Math.instance_eval("binding")
 b.eval("self")
 => Math
```

The documentation for `Kernel#binding` says it "describes the variable and method bindings *at the point of call*". I think that accurately describes the behavior you are seeing with `Math.__send__(:binding)`. The Binding object you get back retains the value of `self` *at the point of call*.